# Error when use different stock tickers from yahoo-> ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, pandas

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer.

When I use AAPL US stock tickers, it works but when I change to Bursa  Malaysia stock tickers which is 0200.KL (REVENUE.KL), it turns out wrong, why?

```
import datetime
import dateutil
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
from stocktrends import Renko

year=5
tickers ="AAPL"
#tickers="0200.KL" #if I replace AAPL stock tickers with this tickers, error occurs
ohlc = wb.get_data_yahoo(tickers,start=datetime.date.today()-dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(years=year),end=datetime.date.today())

def ATR(DF,n):
    "function to calculate True Range and Average True Range"
    df = DF.copy()
    df['H-L']=abs(df['High']-df['Low'])
    df['H-PC']=abs(df['High']-df['Adj Close'].shift(1))
    df['L-PC']=abs(df['Low']-df['Adj Close'].shift(1))
    df['True Range']=df[['H-L','H-PC','L-PC']].max(axis=1,skipna=False)
    df['Average True Range'] = df['True Range'].rolling(n).mean()
    #df2 = df.drop(['H-L','H-PC','L-PC'],axis=1)
    return df["Average True Range"]


def renko_DF(DF):
    "function to convert ohlc data into renko bricks"
    df = DF.copy()
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df = df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,5,6]]
    df.rename(columns = {"Date" : "date", "High" : "high","Low" : "low", "Open" : "open","Adj Close" : "close", "Volume" : "volume"}, inplace = True)
    #df.fillna(method="bfill")
    df2 = Renko(df)
    df2.brick_size = round(ATR(DF,120)[-1],0)
    #renko_df = df2.get_bricks() #i get_bricks() does not work try using get_ohlc_data() instead
    renko_df = df2.get_ohlc_data()
    return renko_df

renko_DF(ohlc)
```

Comment: `df2.brick_size = round(ATR(DF,120)[-1],1)` If you don't use integers in this code, but use, for example, one decimal place, the result will be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The code as below:

```
import datetime
import dateutil
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
from stocktrends import Renko

year=5
tickers ="AAPL"
#tickers="0200.KL" #if I replace AAPL stock tickers with this tickers, error occurs
ohlc = wb.get_data_yahoo(tickers,start=datetime.date.today()-dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(years=year),end=datetime.date.today())

def ATR(DF,n):
    "function to calculate True Range and Average True Range"
    df = DF.copy()
    df['H-L']=abs(df['High']-df['Low'])
    df['H-PC']=abs(df['High']-df['Adj Close'].shift(1))
    df['L-PC']=abs(df['Low']-df['Adj Close'].shift(1))
    df['True Range']=df[['H-L','H-PC','L-PC']].max(axis=1,skipna=False)
    df['Average True Range'] = df['True Range'].rolling(n).mean()
    #df2 = df.drop(['H-L','H-PC','L-PC'],axis=1)
    return df["Average True Range"]


def renko_DF(DF):
    "function to convert ohlc data into renko bricks"
    df = DF.copy()
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df = df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,5,6]]
    df.rename(columns = {"Date" : "date", "High" : "high","Low" : "low", "Open" : "open","Adj Close" : "close", "Volume" : "volume"}, inplace = True)
    #df.fillna(method="bfill")
    df2 = Renko(df)
    df2.brick_size = round(ATR(DF,120)[-1],2)
    renko_df = df2.get_ohlc_data()
    return renko_df

renko_DF(ohlc)
```